# Связанные dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

Есть три датафрейма пандас. Первый связан со вторым одинаковым столбцом, второй - с третьим.

```
   df1: ['A', 'B', 'C']
   df2: ['C', 'D'] 
   df3: ['D', 'E', 'F']
```

Я хочу в первый датафрейм добавить столбцы 'D', 'E', 'F', но так, чтобы значения df1['C'] были равны значениям df2['C'], а df2['D'] были равны df3['D]. В общем, чтобы добавление строк в новые столбцы происходило по условию.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.merge(another)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
res = df1.merge(df2).merge(df3)
```

PS в зависимости от того, что вы хотите получить на выходе, возможно вы захотите использовать параметр “how=‘left’”

Comment: А эта функция "умно" добавляет столбец? Или просто добавляет в новый столбец строк столько, сколько строк было в изначальном фрейме?

Comment: @Boundurant, добавляет «умно», связывая строки по одинаковым значениям из столбцов с одинаковыми именами. Попробуйте на небольших примерах - тогда станет понятнее как это работает

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! @MaxU

Comment: @Boundurant, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа [отметьте ответ как решение и/или проголосуйте за ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)